# How to map years into subsequent decades in R?

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a list of years ranging from 1920 to 2020. I need to convert them to their subsequent decades.
How do I do that effortlessly in R?
I was trying by writing nested if statements but it is becoming too long and tedious.

Sample from my data:

```
data <-structure(list(Years = c(1945L, 1987L, 1980L, 1963L, 2006L, 1995L, 
1971L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Desired output:

[image: Sample]

Any help would mean a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data %>%
  mutate(Decade = if_else(Years >= 2000,
                          paste0(Years  %/% 10 * 10, "'s"),
                          paste0((Years - 1900) %/% 10 * 10, "'s")))
```

The `%/% 10 * 10` bit does the heavy lifting here. `%/%` is the "integer division" operator and it identifies the integer number of decades, then we multiply by 10 to get back to years.

```
  Years Decade
1  1945   40's
2  1987   80's
3  1980   80's
4  1963   60's
5  2006 2000's
6  1995   90's
7  1971   70's
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the required result, if you dont' use the ifelse you'll get 1940's, 1950's etc.

```
data %>% 
    mutate(Decade = paste0(floor(ifelse(Years<2000, Years-1900, Years)/10)*10, "'s"))
```

We could tidy things up by using a function - getDecade.

```
getDecade <- function(year) {
  year <- ifelse(year<2000, year-1900, year)
  decade <- floor(year/10) * 10
  return (decade)
}

data %>% mutate(decade = paste0(getDecade(Years),"'s"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps using substring.. means you don't have to think so much:

(Also condensed code isn't always better code)

```r
decade <- function( year ) {

    decades <- year

    i1 <- year < 2000

    ## first the 19.. decades
    decades[ i1 ] <- paste0( substr( year[ i1 ], 3, 3 ), "0's" )

    ## then the 20.. decades
    decades[ !i1 ] <- paste0( substr( year[ !i1 ], 1, 3 ), "0's" )

    return( decades )

}

data$Decade <- decade( data$Year )
```

Comment: This looks pretty cool. Thanks. Also, pardon my ignorance here, what did you imply there by 'Condensed code'?

Comment: I was un-gementlemanly refering to some of the other answers to this question and similar, where 2-3 chained %>% calls are put up as answers. (I do this too). They are not always better just because they appear short and neat. For the very simplest solutions, sure, but for slightly more complex operations, often you would struggle if you revisit the code later and need to make sense of it.

Comment: note, this thread is not particularly bad, I was more justifying my entry that illustrates a somewhat different and more verbose approach

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data) #converting data into data.table
data[,decade:=paste0(floor(as.numeric(substr(Years,3,4))/10), "0's")]
data[decade=="00's", decade:="2000's"]
data
   Years decade
1:  1945   40's
2:  1987   80's
3:  1980   80's
4:  1963   60's
5:  2006 2000's
6:  1995   90's
7:  1971   70's
```